# async TryParse(...) pattern

Tags: c#, async-await

There are a lot of common `bool TryXXX(out T result)` methods in the .NET BCL, the most popular being, probably, `int.TryParse(...)`.

I would like to implement an **async** `TryXXX()` method. Obviously, I can't use `out` parameters.

Is there an established pattern for this?

More to the point, I need to download and parse a file. It's possible that the file does not exist.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
public async Task<DownloadResult> TryDownloadAndParse(string fileUri)
{
    try
    {
        result = await DownloadAndParse(fileUri); //defined elsewhere
        return new DownloadResult {IsFound = true, Value = result}
    }
    catch (DownloadNotFoundException ex)
    {
        return new DownloadResult {IsFound = false, Value = null}
    }
    //let any other exception pass
}

public struct DownloadResult
{
    public bool IsFound { get; set; }

    public ParsedFile Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Until this syntax https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347 is implemented, it seems you are doomed to just return your own type. At least use Tuple<bool, T> (or better custom type with reasonable property names like Success and Result), not KeyValuePair.

Comment: Thx for the link, nice proposal! What's the benefit of Tuple<> over KVP<> ? I always need to return exactly two items, the true/false result and the actual payload. I kinda hate the property names of `Tuple<>` (`.Item1`, `.Item2`... completely opaque to what the tuple holds.). `KVP` is not much better (in my scenario), but at least `.Value` makes *some* sense.

Comment: Difference is only semantics. KeyValuePair is, well, key + value. In your case nothing is key really. Tuple is just two (or more) arbitrary values - your case. If you don't like names, create your own TryAsyncResult<T> class with bool and T properties with appropriate names. You only need one such class for all your Try operations (because of generics).

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu - http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple-keyvaluepair, worth a read. Performance issue. But in real terms no difference.  Around your initial question, can you explain scenario for wanting async parse? I can't see where I would ever need it async?

Comment: @LordJam my method goes to cloud storage, downloads a file of a particular format and parses it, returning a strongly typed representation. The `Try` part is due to the fact that the file may not exist, and that's a "normal" (i.e. not exceptional) case - it doesn't warrant an exception.

Comment: @LordJam Re: your link - interesting read. However, this is such a micro-optimization. My method takes ~ seconds, which absolutely dwarfs the perf benefit of Tuple vs KVP.

Comment: Note that the function you use in your example is not quite good for general use. You execute arbitrary function and just eat all exceptions, which is bad to do except rare cases (and this is not such case).

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Agree with you, I was trying to point out how minimal the difference was.  And thanks for the exp. Makes sense.

Comment: @Evk I guess this is the exact semantic of this method: "Either it works, or it doesn't". My actual method (which is not generic, see comment above) actually only eats up "expected" exceptions (e.g. file not found) and propagates "exceptional" :) exceptions (e.g. access denied)

Comment: You're using `KeyValuePair` but you don't have a key... That's whats wrong with using that type. Maybe use this: `struct ErrorResult<T> { T Value; Exception Error; }`. Or a boolean instead of the exception.

Comment: @usr That would be the cleanest approach, and I'm leaning towards this, except I don't know how to name the structure. `ErrorResult` seems to imply it's centered around an error, which it is not. `MaybeResult`, maybe? Sounds a bit like a monad. Also, I'd use a bool, not an Exception. If the `TryXXX()` method knows how to handle an error, it should. That's why I'm not calling `XXX()` directly.  And if it can't, I think it should rethrow it, not repackage it.

Comment: Is the int.TryParse just an example or are you actually trying to make integer parsing async? What kind of functions will you wrap like this?

Comment: Using bool is very dangerous because you're swallowing exceptions that way. This tends to hide bugs such as nullrefexceptions. Can lead to systems where you press a button and just nothing happens... And the devs never find out that users hit a problem.

Comment: @usr You're right. That's what I'm saying too - the method should just swallow what it *knows* could go wrong (and it's ok to ignore) and rethrow anything else. I object to having an exception property, because that can easily (and inadvertently) be ignored by the consumer. My original example in the post is more generic than what I actually ended up doing. I should modify that.

Answer (score 5):

I've come up with the following definitions.  The `defaultValue` parameters are there mostly to be able to overload the `TryGet` method, as generic constraints are not part of a method's signature, that which makes the method unique when deciding which method to call (for instance, the return type is also not part of the signature).

```
public async Task<T> TryGet<T>(Func<Task<T>> func, T defaultValue = null) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        return await func();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

public async Task<Nullable<T>> TryGet<T>(Func<Task<T>> func, Nullable<T> defaultValue = null) where T : struct
{
    try
    {
        return await func();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

You should review exception handling, this example handles the common parsing exceptions.  It may make more sense to react to other exceptions, such as `InvalidOperationException` and `NotSupportedException`, probably the most used exception types on the framework itself (not necessarily the most commonly thrown ones).

Another approach is to re-throw critical exceptions, such as `ThreadAbortException` and have a simple catch-all clause that returns the default value.  However, this will hide every exception not deemed critical, no matter how severe it is.

As such, and because throwing exceptions is an expensive operation, it's `Parse` that is usually defined in terms of `TryParse`.  So your `TryGet` should have a contract, e.g. deal with `OperationCanceledException`, which includes `TaskCanceledException` and nothing else.

Finally, you should name it `TryGetAsync`, following the Async-suffix convention. <sup>[[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx)</sup> <sup>[[2]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One of possible decisions is an array of `ParsedFile`, containing 0 or 1 element.

```
public async Task<ParsedFile[]> TryDownloadAndParse(string fileUri)
{
    try
    {
        return new[] { await DownloadAndParse(fileUri) };
    }
    catch (DownloadNotFoundException ex)
    {
        return new ParsedFile[0];
    }
}
```

Now you can check the result:

```
. . .

var parsedFiles = await TryDownloadAndParse(url);
if (parsedFiles.Any())
{
    var parsedFile = parsedFiles.Single();
    // more processing
}

. . .
```

If you want to call `void` method, you can use `?.` operator:

```
var parsedFiles = await TryDownloadAndParse(url);
parsedFiles.SingleOrDefault()?.DoVeryImportantWorkWithoutResult();
```

**UPDATE**

In Azure you can use [`ConditionalValue<TValue>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.conditionalvalue-1?view=servicefabricdata-2.5.216).

Comment: ConditionalValue sounds interesting. That page mentions "Reliable Collections APIs" but no link, and it's lacking in detail...

Comment: PS Found a better link for "Reliable collections" seems to be a service offering of Azure Service Fabric. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections